# Unable to copy SVG images from Wiki to Google Docs

Tags: google-chrome, svg, ms-word, clipboard, google-docs

I've tried to copy a rich text with formulas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion), but it isn't working. Google docs says "Unable to create some images", and Word 2016 just say nothing. My OS is Windows 10. I've tried different browsers (Chrome, Opera, Edge).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs wont accept pasted svg images. A work around (if you have control over your mathjax plugin) is generating those images as .png.